# Send push notification to web browser from android app programmatically

Tags: android, browser, push-notification

Is it possible to send push notification from Android app to web browsers?

I have googled it but not found exact solution.

Please help.

Comment: To `Web Browsers`? What do you mean? Your local browser connected to same IP or “all” the browser? Your question isn’t clear enough.

Comment: I have to send to all the browser.